# Affecting Child CSS Through Code

Tags: css, vb.net

Ok so I'm trying to set an unordered list from display none to block on a button click. I've set the css like so;

```
#ErrorDiv li{ color:#9a005a; font-weight:bold; display:none;}
```

So all my ListItems within my ErrorDiv don't display. Problem is, how do I display them then on a button click? I've tried in my code;

```
ErrorDiv.Style.Add("Display", "block")
```

But obviously this only the ErrorDiv and not the children ListItems. I've also tried calling javascript functions but that was just a bit of a headache. I imagine there must be a simple way I can affect this one style property for the child elements?

Just to be clear, it's not just button click -> Display. There's some work that goes on server side before the Display.

Comment: If you intend for this to be a client-side interaction (as it should be) then you need to use JavaScript to do it. Given you're using .net, jQuery would be a good place to start.

Comment: Nope can't be client side because there's some server work done between the Display and the button click.

Comment: what server side action exactly?

Comment: Calling a Stored Procedure from the back end then analysing returned data to decide whether to display the errorDiv or Redirect from another page.

Comment: If it's server-side, then re-render the page on post back. Otherwise, you could use an AJAX call, then do the show/hide via JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try something like this.

```
     Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     Me.ErrorDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;")
     End Sub
```

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Include the jquery framework in your page and then use the click event

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('#ID').click(function(){
        $('#ErrorDiv li').css({'display':'block'});
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Gonna try that but going to call the function from my VB.

Comment: That's a JS function, so you can't call it directly via VB. You can have VB execute the function upon page rendering. But that's really over-complicating everything.

Comment: Hmm not that complicated was simply doing `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "window-script", "FunctionCall()", True)` but ya you're right, there must be a simpler way.